# Twitter Bootstrap 2 javascript plugins not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Firebug is throwing these errors:

$(document).on is not a function | bootstrap.js (line 786):

```
$(document).on('keyup.dismiss.modal', function ( e ) {
```

$("body").on is not a function | bootstrap.js (line 139):

```
$('body').on('click.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)
```

And then the plugins don't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm loading jquery before bootstrap of course, so I don't know what's the problem. Jquery is working fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nevermind, I was using a different version of jQuery. Downloaded the latest version and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, the [Javascript](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) page says: "**Heads up!** All javascript plugins require the latest version of jQuery."

Answer (score 4):

The `.on()` was added in jQuery version 1.7, and supercedes `delegate()` and `live()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the latest version of jquery from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js