# conflict between bootstrap and JQuery responsive slider

Tags: jquery, jslider

I have a problem with a slider in the layout.
I have a slider and it is working but the image is compressed and distorted, instead of moving, as in the original slider.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $(window).on is not a function
$(window).on( 'smartresize.eislideshow', function( event ) {
```

How can I solve it. I am not familiar with this js.

- [My site](http://b.pusku.com/)
- [Original slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/21/elastic-image-slideshow-with-thumbnail-preview/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 2 javascript plugins not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153428/twitter-bootstrap-2-javascript-plugins-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using jQuery 1.6.4 in the page which doesn't support the `on()` method. This was only introduced in version 1.7 http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Edit**

As well as the lines you have included there are two scripts loading older versions. These are the referencing lines. They must be getting pulled in from your wordpress template.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://b.pusku.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://b.pusku.com/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/js/jquery.js?ver=3.4.2'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I use this line in the header to include query library <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script> I cant undestand where is line with old version. I am not much familiar with js. Tell me if possible where is lines with old versions of Query and i will delete it. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted this files from folders and deleted lines in function.php, but i still have the line <script type='text/javascript' src='http://b.pusku.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script> when i open page source. Could you tell me where can be this script, maybe in another one folder? Thank you!

Comment: I change Jq version by code if (!is_admin()) 
{ wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"), false); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
} and change JQ version of bootstrap and now i dont see any warnings in Furebug but slider still dont working correctly. Maybe cause conflict beetwin slider and bootstrap css.

Comment: Yeah.. its working but only in dekstop mode.. when you try to reduce browser window to mobile screen you will see that imagess is compressed and distorted on slider.. i spent whole day) but cant understand whats the problem..

Comment: You have the css value `max-width:100%` in bootstrap.css (line 69). You need to find the selector `ei-slider-large li img` in slider.css (line 34) and give it the value `max-width:none`.

Comment: WOW! its finally working!) And working well on all devices. James, thank you so much for help!

Comment: [answer]@James Sorry, i am a new one in this forum. When i was asked "Was this post useful to you?" i push "yes" button. But i still can't understand exactly  how i can mark this as the answer and  vote up for userfull answer! I get used to supply plus 1, but how i can do it on this forum? Can you give me the link on this  rule?

Comment: That's totally fine. There should be a little tick next to each answer. Just click that. It will turn green. It's at the bottom [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the faq.

Comment: Thank you, i understand and now i have green tick! I see that i can't vote for answer untill i will have 15 reputation..I wish i could vote and I want to help you again for so userful answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have not one, not two, but 3 different versions of jQuery included in the head of your site!!! (1.8.0, 1.7.2, and lastly, 1.6.4). The last one overwrites the previous 2 and, 1.6.4 does not include the .on() method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used this line to include query in the header